# Selecting among dependencies in Angularjs in production

Tags: angularjs

All the DI documentation in Angular seems to be based on the idea that you want the system implementation of a service when the code is production and when you are running automated tests, you want to select among several mock implementations.

No, I have several working implementations of a dependency and I want to choose one (based typically on the URL).  How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. put your dependencies into separate module. Fore example serviceA.impl1 and serviceA.impl2
2. create the application level module but add dependencies based on URL

```
angular.module('impl1', [])....
angular.module('impl2', [])....

var deps = [];
if (location.match(...) {
  deps.push('impl1')
} else {
  deps.push('impl2')
}

angular.module('myApp', deps);
```

then in your index.html do

```
  <html ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: Thanks, Misko.  As soon as I wrote my first module (about 10 minutes ago), that solution became inevitable.